# XHR GET request fails in background script - Chrome Extension Developing

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to fetch data from an API using XHR.The request will be made when I click on the context item after selecting a some text. I have added permission of my localhost in manifest file and XHR request function in background script. But CORS policy is not allowing it for some reason. In the documentation of Chrome extension it says I must use it in background script. I tried to use it on content script too. It sends request from content script to the server but fails to retrieve data.

Can anyone help me in that case. Thanks in advance.

**manifest.json**

```
 {
"name": "Towel Reviewer",
"version": "1.0",
"description": "Grabing the Header Name & Header Link",
"permissions": [
    "storage","declarativeContent",
    "activeTab","http://localhost/*",
    "contextMenus","tabs","http://*/*",
    "https://*/*", "http://localhost/*",
    "http://localhost/db1/getdata.php?*"],
"background": {
  "scripts": ["background.js","event.js"],
  "persistent": false
},
"browser_action": {
  // "default_popup": "popup.html",
  "default_icon": {
    "16": "images/get_started16.png",
    "32": "images/get_started32.png",
    "48": "images/get_started48.png",
    "128": "images/get_started128.png"
  }
},
"icons": {
  "16": "images/get_started16.png",
  "32": "images/get_started32.png",
  "48": "images/get_started48.png",
  "128": "images/get_started128.png"
},
"content_scripts":[{
    "matches" : ["<all_urls>"],
    "js" : ["jquery-3.4.1.min.js","content.js","popup.js"]
}],

"manifest_version": 2}
```

**background.js**

```
let contextMenuItem ={
  "id":"TowelReviewer",
  "title": "Fetch",
  "contexts":["selection"]
};


function make(urls){
  alert(urls)
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("GET", urls, true);
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
      var resp = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
      console.log(resp);
    }
  }
  xhr.send();

}


chrome.contextMenus.create(contextMenuItem);
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(clickData){
  let pre = "https://amzn";
  if(clickData.menuItemId == "TowelReviewer" && clickData.selectionText ){
    if( (clickData.selectionText+"").startsWith(pre)){
      url = "http://localhost/db1/getdata.php?link=";
      url = url + clickData.selectionText;
      make(url);
    }
  }
})
```

Error From background console:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost/db1/getdata.php?link=https://amzn.to/2asdf' from origin 'chrome-extension://hcilieaalhffbpnnmojonlgkhmebmmcm' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Server status screenshot for fetching data using Postman,
[image]

Comment: Judging by the error message, your server on localhost isn't configured properly.

Comment: @wOxxOm I thought that too , then I used postman to fetch data & it is successful. Status code 200 ok.

Comment: The browser makes the requests differently. See [Why doesn’t Postman get a "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" error when my JavaScript code does?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20035101)

Comment: okay, but how will I fix that problem, on my server it is just basic PHP code to retrieve some data from database , I used sql. Is there anything or any way I should check?
- @wOxxOm

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks, You were right. There was a problem with server configuration. At last fixed it. Just added a line to allow CORS header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"). It may have some security issues, but I'm okay with it.